# Filtering list of tuples based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a given list of tuples, if multiple tuples in the list have the first element of tuple the same - among them select only the tuple with the maximum last element.

For example:

```
sample_list = [(5,16,2),(5,10,3),(5,8,1),(21,24,1)]
```

In the `sample_list` above since the first 3 tuples has the similar first element `5` in this case among them only the 2nd tuple should be retained since it has the max last element => `3`.

Expected op:

```
op = [(5,10,3),(21,24,1)]
```

Code:

```
op = []
for m in range(len(sample_list)):
    li = [sample_list[m]]
    for n in range(len(sample_list)):
        if(sample_list[m][0] == sample_list[n][0]
           and sample_list[m][2] != sample_list[n][2]):
            li.append(sample_list[n])
    op.append(sorted(li,key=lambda dd:dd[2],reverse=True)[0])

print (list(set(op)))
```

This works. But it is very slow for long list. Is there a more pythonic or efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is the list already sorted by first element?

Comment: @MadPhysicist nope not necessarily.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to fit with the description. From your description, the output should be [(5,10,3),(21,24,1)]. Please clarify

Comment: @DarkKnight - you are correct, edited it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the fastest alternative and arguably the most *pythonic*:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sample_list = [(5, 16, 2), (5, 10, 3), (5, 8, 1), (21, 24, 1)]

d = defaultdict(lambda: (0, 0, float("-inf")))
for e in sample_list:
    first, _, last = e
    if d[first][2] < last:
        d[first] = e

res = [*d.values()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1)]
```

This is a single pass `O(n)` which is not only asymptotically optimal but also performant in practice.

### Detailed Explanation

#### Performance

To show that is performant one could design an experiment considering the two main variables of the problem, the number of unique keys (values in the firs position of the tuple) and the length of the input list and the following alternatives approaches:

```
def defaultdict_max_approach(lst):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: (0, 0, float("-inf")))
    for e in lst:
        first, _, last = e
        if d[first][2] < last:
            d[first] = e
    return [*d.values()]


def dict_max_approach(lst):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025193/4001592
    d = {}
    for tpl in lst:
        first, *_, last = tpl
        if first not in d or last > d[first][-1]:
            d[first] = tpl

    return [*d.values()]


def groupby_max_approach(lst):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025193/4001592
    return [max(g, key=ig(-1)) for _, g in groupby(sorted(lst), key=ig(0))]
```

As shown in the plots below the approach using defaultdict is the most performant method for a varying number of unique keys (500, 1000, 5000, 10000) and also for collections up to 1000000 elements (note that the x axis in is in thousands).

[image: Experiments]

The above experiments are in concordance with experiments done by others ([1](https://tomron.net/2014/08/25/setdefault-vs-get-vs-defaultdict/), [2](https://shirishweb.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/python-defaultdict-versus-dict-get/)). The code for reproducing the experiments can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mesejo/8969e069f7077b7a14d8eeba8d0e5ff3).

#### Pythonic

Stating that is the most *pythonic* is subjective, but here are the main arguments in favor:

**Is a well known Python idiom**

Using a defaultdict for grouping  a sequence key-value pairs, and aggregating afterwards, is a well known Python idiom.
Read the [defaultdict examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) in the Python documentation.

In the PyCon 2013 [talk](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger-1?slide=16) *Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python* by Raymond Hettinger also says that using defaultdict for such operations is the *better way*.

**Is compliant with the Zen of Python**

In the Zen of Python it can be read that

> Flat is better than nested.
> Sparse is better than dense.

Using a defaultdict is as flat as using a plain dict only a `for-loop` and a simple `if` statement. In the case of defaultdict the if condition is even simpler.

Both solutions are *sparser* than using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), notice this approach also involves calling [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) all inside a list comprehension.

### Original Answer

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group tuples that have the same first element and then take the maximum of each group based on the third:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sample_list = [(5,16,2),(5,10,3),(5,8,1),(21,24,1)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for e in sample_list:
    d[e[0]].append(e)

res = [max(val, key=lambda x: x[2]) for val in d.values()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1)]
```

This approach is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for readability. Within the groups, apply [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with an appropriate key function, again using `itemgetter` for brevity:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig

lst = [(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1), (5, 8, 1), (5, 16, 2)]

[max(g, key=ig(-1)) for _, g in groupby(sorted(lst), key=ig(0))]
# [(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1)]
```

For a linear-time solution, with extra-space only  bound the number of unique first elements, you may use a `dict`:

```
d = {}
for tpl in lst:
    first, *_, last = tpl
    if first not in d or last > d[first][-1]:
        d[first] = tpl

[*d.values()]
# [(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1)]
```

Comment: Why do you mention `collections.defaultdict` when your second solution doesn't use it? It's just an ordinary `dict`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Fair point, was using one at first, but turned out to be unnecessary.

Comment: the second option is straightforward and as performant as it can be.

Answer (score 5):

Try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
sample_list.sort()
print([max(l, key=lambda x: x[-1]) for _, l in groupby(sample_list, key=lambda x: x[0])])
```

Or also with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
sample_list.sort()
print([max(l, key=itemgetter(-1)) for _, l in groupby(sample_list, key=itemgetter(0))])
```

For performance try:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dct = {}
for i in sample_list:
    if i[0] in dct:
        dct[i[0]].append(i)
    else:
        dct[i[0]] = [i]
print([max(v, key=itemgetter(-1)) for v in dct.values()])
```

All output:

```
[(5, 10, 3), (21, 24, 1)]
```

Comment: Using `sorted` unnecessarily costs *O(n log n)*. Also, using `groupby` requires that the input list be pre-sorted in the first place.

Comment: @blhsing The op stated that they're not sorted necessarily, [python filter list of tuples based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121991550)

Comment: @blhsing Do you mean by sorting first?

Comment: @blhsing Edited my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Yes, actually @DaniMesejo already implemented what I had in mind to solve this in linear time.

Comment: Your updated code still does the same thing. It's the drawback of using `groupby`, that you have to pre-sort the list, which prevents the solution from achieving linear time complexity.

Comment: @blhsing True, yeah

Comment: @blhsing Added one for performance, which is only O(n) I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linear-time method which I think qualifies as more Pythonic:

```
highest = dict()
for a, b, c in sample_list:
     if a not in highest or c >= highest[a][2]:
         highest[a] = (a, b, c)
op = list(highest.values())
```

You can change the `>=` to `>` if you care about how to choose between triples with the same first and last elements but different middle elements.

As pointed out by @AlexWaygood, `dict`s have yielded their elements according to insertion order since Python 3.7. The code above therefore causes the elements of `op` to be in the same order the elements of `sample_list`.

In Python 3.6 or older, on the other hand, the order may change. If you want a solution that works in Python 3.6 too, you will need to use an `OrderedDict`, as in:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

highest = OrderedDict()
for a, b, c in sample_list:
     if a not in highest or c >= highest[a][2]:
         highest[a] = (a, b, c)
op = list(highest.values())
```

Comment: There's no real need to use `OrderedDict` for this, since regular `dict`s have guaranteed insertion order will be preserved since python 3.7. (Other than that, nice answer, albeit somewhat similar to some that have already been posted.)

Comment: I happened to be running Python 3.6 on this machine, but you're right :-)

Comment: Ah that explains it! It might be worth editing your answer to make it clear that your approach is especially useful for those using older versions of python, for whom insertion order of dictionaries isn't guaranteed :)

Comment: Also come join us on python 3.9, it's great!

Comment: (I now included both versions, with clarification.)

Comment: Obscure fun fact btw: it's very marginally more performant to initialise empty dictionaries with `{}` than with `dict()`, due to the fact that function calls are pretty expensive in python.